# Why doesn't numpy support PEP517 builds?

Tags: python, numpy, homebrew, python-poetry

When I run `poetry install`, I get a ChefBuildError when trying to install numpy=(1.25.1); specifically, it says that Backend 'setuptools.build_meta:**legacy**' is not available.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
  at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/poetry/1.7.1/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/poetry/installation/chef.py:164 in _prepare
```

Poetry says that this error originates from the build backend, and is likely not a problem with poetry but with numpy (1.25.1) not supporting PEP 517 builds.

Based on the `ModuleNotFoundError` message, I made sure to install python3.12 with brew. No luck. Per poetry's suggestion, I tried running `pip wheel --no-cache-dir --use-pep517 "numpy (==1.25.1)"`. I got an error that also stated a `ModuleNotFoundError` saying `distutils` cannot be found.

Here is my computing environment

```
System Version: macOS 14.1.2 (23B92)
Kernel Version: Darwin 23.1.0
Homebrew: 4.1.22
Poetry: 1.7.1
Python: 3.12.0
pip: 23.3.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue, and here are the versions of my system and related tools:

System Version: macOS 13.6.4

Kernel Version: Darwin 22.6.0

Homebrew 4.2.5

Poetry (version 1.7.1)

pip 21.2.3

I finally find reason from [this issue](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/7611)

[Distutils is removed in Python 3.12](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/release/1.26.0-notes.html)

The Python versions supported in numpy1.25 release are 3.9-3.11.

Lowering the Python version to 3.10 resolves the issue.

Or upgrade numpy to 1.26.

I ultimately used pyenv to switch Python versions:

```
brew install pyenv
```

[Configure the shell environment according to the official documentation.](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv?tab=readme-ov-file#set-up-your-shell-environment-for-pyenv)

After restarting the terminal to apply changes, install Python 3.10.0:

```
pyenv install 3.10.0
```

Switch Python version:

```
pyenv local 3.10.0
```

or

```
pyenv global 3.10.0
```

After confirming the version switch, remember to switch the Python virtual environment of the Poetry project to 3.10.0:

```
poetry env use 3.10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

numpy requires Python >=3.9

Update pyproject.toml

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.9,<4.0"

Comment: Numpy has been around since long before Python 3.9 was created, so I'm really not sure what you mean here.

Answer (score -1):

Here are simplified steps to help you resolve the problem:

Install Xcode Command Line Tools:
Make sure you have Xcode Command Line Tools installed on your macOS. Run **xcode-select --install to get them.**

Install Python with Homebrew:
Uninstall and then reinstall Python using Homebrew with these commands:

**brew uninstall python
brew install python
Check Python Version:
Confirm you're using Python 3.12.0, and it's activated in your virtual environment or globally.**

Update Poetry:
Keep Poetry up-to-date with:

**poetry self update**

Update Pip:
**Ensure your pip is up-to-date:**
**poetry run pip install --upgrade pip**
Install NumPy:
Try using Poetry to install NumPy directly:
**poetry add numpy==1.25.1**
Clean Cache:
Clear the Poetry cache to avoid any caching issues:

**poetry cache clear --all
Re-run Poetry Install:**
After these changes, attempt poetry install again:
**poetry install**